# Dynamic keys and properties in object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to make an object with counters for every type of `houseType`, from an array of objects; idea is for the keys and properties to be dynamic in order to account for potential new `houseType`'s.

From:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    name: 'House sth',
    desc: 'lorem ipsum',
    type: 'house'
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Building sth',
    desc: 'lorem ipsum',
    type: 'building'
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: 'House two',
    desc: 'lorem ipsum',
    type: 'house'
}]
```

To this result:
`{ house: 2, building: 1 }` *(two of type === 'house' and one of type === 'building')*

The next was my approach, but of course the values are `NaN`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    listings.map((listing, index) => {
      setPropertyCount(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        [listing.type]: prevState[listing.type] + 1,
      }));
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: Side note: Using `map` when you're not using the array it creates and returns is an anti-pattern, details on my blog [here](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/04/17/misusing-map/).

Comment: As T.J Crowder mentioned use `forEach` instead of `map`. And Issue is you are trying to do `undefined + 1` operation at the start and gets `NaN`. Try this => `[listing.type]: (prevState[listing.type] ?? 0) + 1`. Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator